# Error with connect to database in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When i try to connect with SQL server database(in Connection Managers) Connection Manager shows me error

> : Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Login timeout expired
>   A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured 
>   to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the broadness of your question I can only direct you to some troubleshooting guides or similar questions:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2014/10/24/tips-and-tricks-to-fix-sql-connectivity-issues/
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5b792971-2b12-469c-9d1d-32ae8ac92ccc/problems-with-connection-manager?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: thank you, but i resolved. I should have just copying Server name from SQL server to Server name in Connection manager. I hope that problem help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround (but definitely not a complete long-term solution) to this error that usually works is to run it from the `DTEXEC utility`.
I really can't understand why but usually it can be executed with DTEXEC but not from Visual Studio in debug mode.

You can simply try writing the following code in TXT editor and save it as `Package1.cmd`, then execute.

```
dtexec /FILE "C:\Users\XYZ\Package1.dtsx" /REP V>"C:\Users\XYZ\Package1.txt"
```

This will also provide a detailed `Package1.txt` log file of the execution.